# How to mount removable media in /media/<LABEL> automatically when inserted, without any desktop environment?

Tags: linux, automount, hotplug, removable-media

I have a Debian sid system (Wheezy) (and same question for arch as well), without any desktop environment (and no Xorg at all).

I can mount my SD-cards, USB sticks, external HDD manually with mount / umount with the suitable entries in `/etc/fstab` but this is compelling, and to restrictive: if I want them to be mounted in `/media/<LABEL>` each device with a different `<LABEL>` needs its own entry, and each `<LABEL>` directory needs to be created / removed manually in `/media/` as well).

So, what is the best way to mount them automatically in `/media/<LABEL>` at insertion (and to unmount them from the filesystem as soon as they are unplugged)?

The ideal solution would:

1. detect when a removable media is plugged-in (added in `/dev/` as
   `sdax`, `sdbx`, ... by `udev`)
2. create a directory in `/media/` according to its label (label of the removable media)
3. mount it in the directory `/media/<LABEL>` in RW mode (if it's filesystem is supported)
4. detect if the media has been unplugged
5. if then, unmout it from the filesystem
6. remove the corresponding directory from `/media/`

(the devices should be mounted in synchronous mode oviously, to avoid any data loss when hot unplugged because of caching)

I found some info about `autofs`, `HAL`, `udisks`, `udisks2`, etc., but it's unclear which one is deprecated or preferred, and anyway, I haven't figured out how to configure them easily on my system to do that, up to now ...

Minimalism, elegance, KISS, *nix-minded, no crazy unbearable XML policies files, and up-to-date highly appreciated.

**edit:** trying to make my question more clear

Comment: I posted my questions on http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44454, maybe I'll have some more answers ... I'm not sure whether it should be deleted from here or not?

Comment: you did same post in diferent sites, with same answer in both self answered...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, it's been a long time, but I'll still answer my question with the best option I found as of now.

The best way is to create a `udev` rule, associated with some scripts (that will create / remove directories and mount / unmount removable devices), and attached to `partition` `udev` device event type.

**1 - Creating add / remove scripts**

Add this script `storage-automount.sh` in `/lib/udev/` and set it to executable (`sudo chmod +x /lib/udev/storage-automount.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh

# set the mountpoint name according to partition or device name
mount_point=$ID_FS_LABEL
if [ -z $mount_point ]; then
    mount_point=${DEVNAME##*/}
fi

# if a plugdev group exist, retrieve its gid set & it as owner of mountpoint
plugdev_gid="$(grep plugdev /etc/group|cut -f3 -d:)"
if [ -z $plugdev_gid ]; then
    gid=''
else
    chown root:plugdev $mount_point
    gid=",gid=$plugdev_gid"
fi

# create the mountpoint directory in /media/ (if not empty)
if [ -n $mount_point ]; then
    mkdir -p /media/$mount_point
    # other options (breaks POSIX): noatime,nodiratime,nosuid,nodev
    mount -t $ID_FS_TYPE \
      -o rw,flush,user,uid=0$gid,umask=002,dmask=002,fmask=002 \
      $DEVNAME /media/$mount_point
fi
```

Add this script `storage-autounmount.sh` in `/lib/udev/` and set it to executable (`sudo chmod +x /lib/udev/storage-autounmount.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh

# set the mountpoint name according to partition or device name
mount_point=$ID_FS_LABEL
if [ -z $mount_point ]; then
    mount_point=${DEVNAME##*/}
fi

# remove the mountpoint directory from /media/ (if not empty)
if [ -n $mount_point ]; then
    umount -l /media/$mount_point
    rm -R /media/$mount_point
fi
```

**2 - Creating the `udev` rule to attach those scripts to events**

And finally, add a `udev` rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d`, for instance `85-storage-automount.rules`:

```
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", RUN+="/lib/udev/storage-automount.sh", ENV{REMOVE_CMD}="/lib/udev/storage-autounmount.sh"
```

And that's it.

Now, when you plug a storage device in, a directory will be created in `/media/` according to the partition name (I don't remember but I think it's working with NTFS partitions as well) and your partition will be mounted into it. It's R/W for users if you have a `plugdev` group on your system. Also, the devices are mounted in synchronous mode in order to limit the risks of data loss in case of hot unplugging.

When the device is removed, it's unmounted and the directory is removed from `/media`.

Also, the tool to monitor the `udev` events is `udevadm monitor`, with options like `--env` or `--property`:

```
$ udevadm monitor --env
```

This is tested and working fine on both Debian and Arch, but probably works on all distributions that rely on `udev`.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check your `/dev/disk/by-uuid` directory while those specific drives are plugged-in. Using `ls -l` it will show you the devices (e.g. `/dev/sdb1`) along with their uuids. Having found the matches, update your `/etc/fstab` accordingly, replacing `/dev/sd*` with the corresponding `/dev/disk/by-uuid/*` entry.

For details, see my answer to [How do I prevent USB flash drive from getting a new Linux device name after wake from sleep?](https://superuser.com/questions/451907/how-do-i-prevent-usb-flash-drive-from-getting-a-new-linux-device-name-after-wake).

Comment: Actually, as I said, the devices are plugged in, I know their UUID/LABEL through either `blkid` or the `/dev/disk/by-uuid` directory. And I can mount them manually as well.

Now, I already have them in `/etc/fstab`, actually eiter by `label` or by `UUID`, both work correctly. That doesn't really help though, since they are mounted at boot time only (as long as I do not specify `noauto`). But if I remove them and if I reinsert them while the system is running, they are not automatically unmounted / mouted in the directories I specified in `fstab`... This is my problem.

Comment: Looks like something weird -- as I use it for years for removables (e.g. SD-cards from my cameras, mobile devices as MP3 player, smartphones, tablets... And they all mount correctly at the designated mountpoint. If you remove them: do you unmount before, and mount again when re-inserting? You should do so, and then it should work.

Comment: If I unmount them and mount them manually, everything works fine obviously. But my problem is that I want them to unmount (`sync` option in `fstab`) and mount them *automatically* (and as `user` as well as `root`) when I remove / insert them. That's why I guess either `AutoFS`, `HAL`, `udisks`, `udisks2` (or `hotplug`, maybe ...?) or something similar is involved... But don't know what I'm missing exactly.

Comment: You probably miss that you still must unmount them manually -- or how shall the system know you're about to do that? Obvioulsy, once you unplugged it cannot be sync'd anymore, and neither cleanly unmounted. So the system assumes some drive-error -- but many times only discards the "old drive" *after* you plugged in the "new drive" again. So on auto-mount, the old mount point is still occupied -- which makes the "new" drive mount elsewhere.

Comment: The hot plug / unplug system like `hal` (amongst others mentionned) should take care of unmounting the device of the fs if it's not plugged anymore. The `sync` option in `/etc/fstab` is used in this case for syncing the files of the device without caching, though avoiding data loss when hot-unplugging (w/o unmounting manually before).

Comment: I know what `mounting` and `unmounting` mean, and that's exactly the same when I unmount manually. My problem is not here. I know how to mount and unmount at startup, or manually, but I'm looking for an **automatic** solution for hot plugging and unplugging removable devices. I know that `HAL` and the others do that, but I don't know how and which is the most elegant way (no crazy XML policy files, just fstab based if possible)

Comment: Now I got it -- sorry for the misunderstanding. Was not quite clear from the orig question.

Comment: No problem :] I know it's not very clear in my question, I'm not sure about the terminology (I'm probably misusing `automounting` and `hotplug` here) ... Thanks for trying to help anyway :]

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with hotplug in the way you need it to give you more help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your hints. I simplified your mount and unmount scripts like this:

mount:

```
#!/bin/sh

udisks --mount $DEVNAME
```

unmount:

```
#!/bin/sh

udisks --unmount $DEVNAME
```

My /etc/udev/rules.d/ file looks like this:

```
# UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED
# ==1: mount filesystem to a shared directory (/media/VolumeName)
# ==0: mount filesystem to a private directory (/run/media/$USER/VolumeName)
# See udisks(8)
ENV{ID_FS_USAGE}=="filesystem|other|crypto",       ENV{UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED}="1"
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", RUN+="/lib/udev/storage-automount.sh",     ENV{REMOVE_CMD}="/lib/udev/storage-autounmount.sh"
```

It's simple and should be a typical use case.

Comment: 8 years later, this is not working anymore, as we might have to use `udisksctl` instead of `udisks`, and `udisksctl seems too slow, that it can't yet mount, when `udev` asks for it.